# Sitecore language embedding and default language

Tags: sitecore, multilingual

The business has a requirement to always show the language in the URL for our CD sites. I did some research and set the LanguageEmbedding setting to always. This seems to work fine for non-default languages but not for English, which is the default language.

When I try to go to www.abc.com, shouldnt it change to www.abc.com/en ? Am I right to think this or is this how Sitecore will behave for default language where it won't show the language if its not an embedded links?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB that is the way that Sitecore works. When you have LanguageEmbedding="always" - the links should all be generated with the language embedded - including for en, so a link to the home page would be `www.abc.com/en` - but if you just visit the domain - `www.abc.com` - Sitecore then uses either the language cookie stored from your last visit, or the default language.

If you want the behavior to be that if you visit `www.abc.com` the user is *always* it would be better to set that up using an IIS Redirect or a rewrite .

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Just doing a redirect on the home page won't be enough if you want consistent behavior from an offsite link or direct URL in the browser. Blanket IIS-only redirect rules to sub pages become especially difficult if say a user's language is set via the language resolver to "es" (i.e. do you redirect /products to /en/products or /es/products?)

Answer (score 2):

When Sitecore determines your language via browser preference, cookie, URL slug, or query string, it will **not** redirect to that preferred URL structure with language slug.

You can either create a redirect module (i.e. if language context set, make correct URL and redirect) or write out `<link langref="">` tags, which is an SEO best practice anyways.